# Draw thumbs (circles) for UISlider in an underlying UIView at equal distance

Tags: swift, xcode, slider, uislider

I had to create a slider having thumbs (small dots or circles) as shown below:

[image]

I simply added a UISlider and added an underlying UIView for holding those dots/thumbs as shown in figure below:

[image]

I put dots in a stack view, gave stack view proportional width (100%) within container, and set its distribution property to "Fill Equally".  Now it seems almost fine, but if you look at it closely you'll notice that the distance between the dots is not same.

Can someone guide me on how to make those dots appear at equal distance.

OR

I wonder if I could create a dedicated custom control and just put it behind UISlider.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check to space in stackView attribute inspector?

Comment: Stack view's spacing attribute is set to 0. First and last UIView in stack view have their dot's leading/trailing space set to 0. And central dots are center aligned (horizontally).

Comment: Give UIView fix width and height then embed in stackView, then set leading trailing constraints and before setting constraint change stackView property in attribute inspector.